# Is is possible to bind a submit() function before any existing onsubmit/submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with an `onsubmit` attribute. I need to bind a new submit event and I need this one to be executed before any existing submit functions.

The following code demonstrates the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(function($) {
        // a plugin
        $('form').submit(function() {
          alert("Second");
        });
        // an other plugin
        $('form').submit(function() {
          alert("Third");
        });

        // this event must always be executed as first event
        $('form').submit(function() {
          alert("Always First");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form onsubmit="javascript:alert('Fourth');">
      <p>
        <input type="submit">
      </p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you execute the script, first you get "Second", then "First".

Is is possible to bind a new submit event and specify whether the function must be called before any existing event?

Constraints:

- Existing events must be preserved.
- I can't remove existing events because the content of the `onsubmit` attribute contains a quite complex logic written by Rails
- (ADDED): the event should always be executed before any existing onsubmit event and already binded events (perhaps binded by an other plugin)

Any idea?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The inline submit event fires first, you could get a reference to it, nullify the `onsubmit` attribute on the `form` element, and then bind your new submit event, this one will execute your *old* submit handler:

```
  jQuery(function($) {
    var form = $('form'), oldSubmit = form[0].onsubmit;
    form[0].onsubmit = null;

    $('form').submit(function() {
      alert("First");
      oldSubmit.call(this); // preserve the context
    });
  });
```

Note that I use the `call` method to invoke your old submit handler, this is to preserve the `this` keyword inside that function, it will be the `form` element itself.

If your original `onsubmit` handler has some validation behavior, you can get its return value by `var ret = oldSubmit.call(this);`

Check the above example [here](http://oldSubmit.call(this);).

Comment: This solution works great. I forgot to mention, other plugins might already have binded other events to the same form. Is it possible bind the event before any onsubmit/binded event? I tried to use unbind/bind (also reading the implementation of the clone function) but I couldn't get a reasonable solution.

Comment: You may try the die() function since many plugins use live() to capture the submit event! http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 3):

Take the existing `submit` handler and store it in a variable.

Then in your new handler, call that function that you stored from the previous `submit` handler, and re-assign your new one to the listener.

Example:

```
  jQuery(function($) {

    $('form').submit(function() {
         var first = this.onsubmit;
         //...
         first.call( this );
    });
  });
```

...or something like that. :=)

Comment: `unbind` will not work to remove the inline `onsubmit` event handler, and the `Function` constructor approach could don't work on some browsers since it relies on the `Function.prototype.toString` method, (to pass the `functionBody` argument as a String) that method is implementation-dependent, I think is safer to use references and avoid the *evaling* done by the `Function` constructor

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343893/jquery-submit-workaround/3344084#3344084) is a better way if it works which it should because the OP has accepted it.