# jQuery submit workaround

Tags: jquery, submit

I found something interesting in jQuery, and I wanted to run it by some folks who understand it better than me to see if there is a solution for it.  So I want to post back the scroll position of the page when submitting all forms on my page.  I can do this by doing the following:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="scroll_position" value="' + $(document).scrollTop() + '" />');
    return true;
}
```

This works as expected when user click or presses enter on the submit button, but there are times where I fire the .submit() event.  Example of this:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    ...
    // Doing something special here
    ...
    $(this).parents('form')[0].submit();
}
```

How would I go about getting my custom submit callback to be called whenever the page is submitted regardless of it being initiated by a .submit() call or the user submitting a form?

Comment: I made an example o jsbin:

http://jsbin.com/ixiza/edit

I would expect both buttons to execute the submit function.  Hope this clears things up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to make new function, if you don't want.
You just have to use jquery's `.submit()` and your work is done. Check the difference.

```
$('button').click(function() {
    ...
    // Doing something special here
    ...
    var form = $(this).parents('form')[0];
    $(form).submit();
}
```

Happy Coding.

Comment: perfect.  I guess I would be interesting in learning whats the difference between: $(this).parents('form')[0].submit(); and var form = $(this).parents('form')[0]; $(form).submit();

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function for that and call it before submitting:

```
function storePosition(){
  $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="scroll_position" value="' + $(document).scrollTop() + '" />');
}
```

Later you can do:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    storePosition();
    return true;
}
```

Or:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    ...
    // Doing something special here
    ...

    storePosition();
    $(this).parents('form')[0].submit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFrmSubmit(){
    $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="scroll_position" value="' + $(document).scrollTop() + '" />');
    return true;
}

$('form').submit(myFrmSubmit);
$('button').click(function() {
    ...
    // Doing something special here
    ...
    myFrmSubmit();
    $(this).parents('form')[0].submit();
}
```